# How to handle lazy loading when using global sidebar in angular?

Tags: angular

I have a sidebar in my root module so that it will be shared among all the other modules. The sidebar loads different components depending upon the selection. To make this possible I have to declare all these components in the root module. Now I would like to lazy load these components(declare in module other than root) but don't know how to. Is there a way to have a global sidebar as I mentioned and also be able to lazy load the components that it will be loading ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple router-outlet in an angular application...

Create a component specifically for the sidebar and declare it in global i.e app.module.

Make the main div, hold the main router-outlet and work normally.

In the sidebar put the secondary router-outlet and load the sidebar module in it and lazy load all the children components.

Credits - u/StarOfTheMoon